# ¿Cómo hacer para que un archivo en específico (dentro de proyecto java) pueda ser abierto desde cualquier computadora?

Tags: java, archivo, csv, rutas

Necesito trabajar con datos de un archivo .csv, y el programa debe correr en cualquier computadora. En mi máquina (trabajo en eclipse con SO ubuntu) funciona perfectamente el programa, pero soy consciente de que cuando lo construya o pase la carpeta con el proyecto para su evaluación en otra PC se levantará una excepción pues el archivo no se encontrará y no se podrán realizar los cálculos.
Abrí el archivo con la siguiente línea:

```
BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/gilberto/workspace/P1DescriptoresEstadisticos/src/Archivos/C1.csv"));
```

Como se puede ver, dentro de la carpeta src está una carpeta con el archivo C1.csv donde se encuentran los datos, y en carpetas distintas, dentro de src, se encuentran las clases.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a usar getClass().getResource(url).getPath(), y añade tu fichero csv al jar de tu proyecto java.

Por ejemplo, si pones tu CSV en el paquete "gilberto.csv", y suponiendo que tienes una clase que se llame "MiClase"
Podras poner la linea:

```
BufferedReader br2 = new FileInputStream(
new File(MiClase.class.getResourceAsStream("gilberto/csv/C1.csv")));
```

Comment: getClass().getResource(url).getPath() , ¿para qué sirve?

Comment: para abrir un archivo, que este en tu classpath. Es decir, en vez de buscar en los archivos en el sistema de ficheros, los buscaria, como si fuera un fichero properties.